# Caliburn mirco not finding view at design tim

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a pretty simple WPF test application with following layout
ViewModels
--DialogViewModel
--GraphViewModel
Views
--DialogView
--GraphView

DialogViewModel has this code:

```
public class DialogViewModel : Screen {
    #region Graph
    private GraphViewModel m_gvmGraph;
    public GraphViewModel Graph {
        get {
            if(m_gvmGraph == null) {
                m_gvmGraph = new GraphViewModel();
            }
            return m_gvmGraph;
        }
        set {
            if(m_gvmGraph != value) {
                m_gvmGraph = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Graph");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public DialogViewModel() {
        DisplayName = "Graph Dialog";
    }
```

GraphViewModel has no code.

DialogView (UserControl) looks like this:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=VMs:DialogViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
Cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
Width="1000" Height="600">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Graph"  />
</Grid>
```

GraphView (UserControl) looks like this:

```
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=VMs:GraphViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
Cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Test" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

(I need the nested Grids later - doesn't matter here).

This works as expecte at runtime (View load and so forth).
So  I guess (most) is done right.

But at design time (when I open GraphView.xaml I get "Cannot find view for XXXX.ViewModels.GraphViewModel."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I've dug into this before.  I had a VS open with the CM source and a VS open with the project source.  With the VS that has the CM source I'd attach to the other VS with the project.  Then in the VS with the project, open the view.

If I remember correctly, in design time, the `SelectAssemblies` collection didn't contain the assembly that contained the views and view models.

I believe I ended up overriding `SelectAssemblies` method in the bootstrapper and if the `Execute.IsInDesignMode` was true, adding the assembly that contained the views and view models even though it was the main/only assembly.